# Having trouble getting a new layout to work as desired in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a hyperlink in the figure caption on my project and the link only appears to work when in mobile view / or small screen where the columns collapse. For some reason, this issue isn't replicated on JFiddle but it is when I test on a variety of browsers and devices.

I discovered that with my old code, the paragraph's area was overlapping the hyperlink's hoverable clicking space, and making it impossible to click until the image would stack above on smaller screen/mobile in the old code.

```
**Old HTML** JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LybeppL3/7/
```

[image: Old HTML Desktop View]
[image: Old HTML Mobile View]

```
**So I tired a workaround**: see Current Code:           https://jsfiddle.net/5c2sm9s1/1/
```

OR  @ PreemPrice.com

Specifically, I am trying now to break up a column for the picture on the right, the paragraphs of text to it's left, and when on mobile, that the picture stacks above the paragraphs of text and is centered.

However, my workaround does not look as nice/ not as responsive on mobile as my old code.

[image: Nicer aesthetic in desktop for workaround]
[image: The image scales down instead of maintaining its size as it did in the old code. And also looks pretty ugly as it does so. Another thing I don't like is that unlike the old code, this new code has the picture stacking below the paragraphs and not centered...]

Specifically, I miss how in the "old" code, see JFiddle, it is really responsive in that the image keeps the same size, and once it's too big, it collapses over the text. In my current work-around, the photo shrinks uglily, and then stacks below instead of above the paragraphs.

Also, I miss how the image is fully centered at the top in mobile device in the old code.

I would appreciate help in getting this to work properly! Thanks!

Comment: You have included your HTML, is there any JS/CSS to include, in order to replicate the problem? If I understand correctly, you have included the CSS/JS for your workaround... If there is no additional CSS/JS for the above HTML, then I can click on the 'Test' link and it works fine

Comment: @Sarhang the CSS is the same for the original and the workaround. There isn't any JS that affects this core problem, its just animation stuff. I tried to keep this as simple as possible. The only difference between my attempt of a workaround and the original is just HTML

Comment: I am not getting the issue... using the HTML and CSS, I can click on the test link... did you say it is not working for you?

Comment: @Sarhang I think it's depending on how wide your browser is. For most of the large sizes it won't click. But when the picture collapses above the body of text, then it becomes clickable. See preemprice.com

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue. I copy pasted your HTML and CSS in JSFiddle, with a large screen and 'Test' is clickable. Would be good if you could include a code snippet or JSFiddle example.

Comment: @Sarhang I think I made my question more clear now and added some JFiddle. For some reason I cannot replicate this issue on JFiddle. But, I would appreciate if you can help me getting my workaround (JFiddle 2; 2 column design) to behave similarly to the old code (JFiddle 1; 1 column design) as I explain above

Comment: The click on the old code seems to work for me.

Comment: @OliverNi it works on JFiddle but not on localhost or on the production site. Chrome dev tools shows the paragraph "covering up" the clickable area of the hyperlink. Can you help me fix up my workaround?

Comment: I have copied your old code in an html text file, along with the CSS. I opened the file in various versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome. I could always click on the link...