# Issues centering a figure in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am changing from an old layout 
**Old HTML** 
`JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LybeppL3/11/`

To a new one **Current Code**: 
     `https://jsfiddle.net/5c2sm9s1/23/`
OR  @ PreemPrice.com

and am having trouble getting my new layout to behave the same way responsively as my old one. Specifically, two things.

1. The figure/image collapses BELOW instead if ABOVE the body of paragraphs as I'd like.
2. The image collapses un-centered unlike my previous code.

Currently, my new code looks nicer on desktop than the previous version. (The picture doesn't cut into the text). But it is currently not as nice looking in mobile as was the old one.

**Mobile look of the old code. What I wan't my new code to look like in mobile**

[image: What I want the new code to do]

**Aesthetic issues with the new code. What I want to fix**

Notice how this demonstrates the two issues I outlined in the list above. Stacks below instead of above the paragraphs, and is not centered.

I would like to fix these issues so that it matches the look of the old code (1)

[image: What the new code is currently doing. Demonstrates the two issues I outlined in the list above. I would like to fix these issues so that it matches the look of the old code (1)]

I would appreciate help in getting this to work properly! Thanks!

Comment: Didn’t you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471123/having-trouble-getting-a-new-layout-to-work-as-desired-in-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the picture div above the div with the text block. And then you'll need to ad an ID to the picture div, and align it to the center using CSS.

The updated HTML code would look like this:

```
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Issue</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <section id= "about">
            <div class= "container containerPadding">
             <div class= "row justify-content-center">
                 <div class= "col-sm-12">
                     <h1 class="text-center ExperienceName">About Us</h1>
                     <h4 class="text-center pb-3">From Humble Beginnings.</h4>
                 </div>

             </div>

            <div class= "row justify-content-center">

                     <div id='profile-pic' class="col-sm-3">
                      <figure class="figure ez-animate text-center" id="profilePic" data-animation="fadeInRight">
                           <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" width="250" height="250" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded ez-animate" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure." data-animation="fadeInRight">
                      <figcaption class="figure-caption"><a href="https://josephromo.com">Joseph A. Romo</a> | Co-Founder & CEO</figcaption>
                  </figure> 
              </div>
                 <div class= "col-sm-9">
                     <p class="text-justify pt-4 ez-animate" data-animation="fadeInUp"> PreemPrice.com LLC was established in 2010 by Joseph A. Romo. An observant middle school student at the time, Joseph became frustrated with the large mark-ups that retailers and manufacturers would impose on seemingly simple products. 
                     </p>

                     <p class="text-justify ez-animate" data-animation="fadeInUp"> As an ambitious attempt to tackle this challenge, Joseph established LivingRoyal.com, a small drop-shipping operation that focused on selling a wide variety of consumer goods and electronics. After encountering some challenges, Joseph decided to re-evaluate the business model and consider entering a much more niche market. It is here where the PreemPrice.com of today was born. 
                     </p>

                     <p class="text-justify ez-animate" data-animation="fadeInUp"> Rather than offering as wide of an array of products, PreemPrice decided to focus on selling a handful of select products-five or less-that were widely used, had fast turn-over, and would be able to offer to customers at a much deeper discount than that of its competitors. These products included toilet tissue, latex medical examination gloves, and the most successful, GatorCase®, a proprietary line of mobile electronic accessories. </p>

                     <p class="text-justify ez-animate" data-animation="fadeInUp">At the heart of PreemPrice's mission is to provide our customers with the utmost quality and value on widely used select products. Today, PreemPrice continues selling items under the GatorCase® brand, while operating on a dynamic basis-a novel eCommerce business model that we created, where we put up products for sale only once we have secured a deal that we know our customers will absolutely love. 
                     </p>
                 </div>


             </div>
         </div>          
     </section>



   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The updated CSS code would look like this:

```
#profile-pic {
  text-align: center
}
```

You can find the updated Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5c2sm9s1/21/).

Comment: Hey! thanks for the reply. Is there a way to change the order of the stacking? Say for example I want the photo to be to the right of the paragraphs on desktop (meaning the photo div would be below the paragraph div), is there a way to have the photo than stack on TOP of the paragraphs instead of it going to the bottom on a mobile screen as it would do by default in this case? I was thinking about push/pull classes from Bootstrap?

Comment: That yeah I got rid of that but I wanted to have the pic load to the right of the paragraphs  and then stack up above it on smaller screen. Currently I have the div literally Before the paragraph div so that’s why it stacks first, but it loads the pic to the left of the paragraphs...